# Accessing scanned image via Scanner hardware in html5/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm implementing one web app in which I need to add one scanner button.After clicking on that button, physical document should be scanned using scanner connected to same computer or from remote location and I should get that image in my web app.Any idea how can it be done?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.I used DynamSoft library to scan and get image on UI.
Link for DynamSoft- http://developer.dynamsoft.com/dwt